# adding a Object in different array dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to add a object to 4 different array like a loop. when the "type" is matching the first object should go the topArray & the second object should go to bottomArray & the third object should go to rightArray like a loop and also the portId should also change with respective array for example if the first object is going to topArray the portId should be top0 after one loop the five object should go to topArray & the portId should be top1 and so on......

Here is the code.

```
this.comps.forEach((comp) => {
      arrayPorts = [];

        let portlist = comp.ports;
  console.log(portlist);
        portlist.forEach((po) => {
          switch (po.type) {
            case 'rest':
           let  docu1 = {
                "portId": "right0",
                "portColor": "#ff0000",
                "portname": "rest"
              }
              arrayPorts.push(docu1);
              break;
            case 'restcon':
            let  docu2 = {
                "portId": "right0",
                "portColor": "#ff8c8c",
                "portname": "restcon"
              }
              arrayPorts.push(docu2);
              break;
            case 'message':
            let  docu3 = {
                "portId": "right0",
                "portColor": "#006600",
                "portname": "message"
              }
              arrayPorts.push(docu3);
              break;
            case 'messagecon':
            let  docu4 = {
                "portId": "right0",
                "portColor": "#00b300",
                "portname": "messagecon"
              }
              arrayPorts.push(docu4);
              break;
            case 'event':
            let docu5 = {
                "portId": "right0",
                "portColor": "#0019ff",
                "portname": "event"
              }
              arrayPorts.push(docu5);
              break;
            case 'eventcon':
            let  docu6 = {
                "portId": "right0",
                "portColor": "#9ea7ff",
                "portname": "eventcon"
              }
              arrayPorts.push(docu6);
              break;
          }

        })
        this.components.push({
          key: finalindex + 1,
          name: this.reComps[comp._id].name,
          id: comp._id,
          version: "Ver: " + comp.version,
          icon: this.reComps[comp._id].icon,
          loc: "",
          group: this.num,
          topArray: arrayPorts,
          bottomArray: [],
          rightArray: [],
          leftArray: [],

        })
        finalindex++;
      }

    });
```

the comp.ports contain array of objects

here is the final output i need

```
{id: "abcd"
icon: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAPoA"
key: 10
loc: ""
name: "ABCD"
topArray: [{"portId":"top0", "portColor":"#ff0000", "portname":"rest"},{"portId":"top1", "portColor":"#ff0000", "portname":"message"}]
bottomArray: [{"portId":"bottom0", "portColor":"#ff8c8c", "portname":"event"},
{"portId":"bottom1", "portColor":"#ff0000", "portname":"message"}]
rightArray: [{"portId":"right0", "portColor":"#0019ff", "portname":"message"}]
leftArray: [{"portId":"left0", "portColor":"#ffff33", "portname":"rest"}]
version: "Ver: 10.1.0"}
```

I need to push the object in a loop for this array  (topArray,bottomArray,rightArray,leftArray) i am finding bit confuse.
Please help me with this issue.

Comment: what is the `type` or where is the `type` here ?

Comment: switch (po.type) {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you need to push the ports to their respective array. This is one way to do it.

```js
const arrays = {
    left: [],
    right: [],
    top: [],
    bottom: []
};

const ports = [{
    "portId": "top0",
    "portColor": "#ff0000",
    "portname": "rest"
}, {
    "portId": "left0",
    "portColor": "#ff0000",
    "portname": "rest"
}, {
    "portId": "bottom0",
    "portColor": "#ff0000",
    "portname": "rest"
}];

ports.forEach((port) => {

    Object.keys(arrays).forEach((key) => {
        
        // Create a regular expression to match the portId
        
        const regEx = `${key}[0-9]*`;

        const arrayToPush = port.portId.match(new RegExp(regEx));
        
        // If we have found the correct array push the port there
        
        if (arrayToPush) arrays[key].push(port);
    });
});

console.log(arrays);
```